# php mysql football standings table script doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I just tried out this code below and it doesn't seem to work. I corrected the bugs and it doesn't show nothing. It should show the standings array which I can then make it into a table. It's for Joomla MVC component that I'm working on. Can maybe somebody help me?

Thanks!

The code:  EDIT:

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('home' , 'scoreHome' , 'away' , 'scoreAway')));
   $query->from($db->quoteName('futliga_pc_liga1'));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadAssocList();

$standings = array ();
$standingTemplate = array ('matches' => 0, 'wins' => 0, 'draws' => 0,    'losses' => 0, 'scoreHome' => 0, 'scoreAway' => 0, 'goalsdiff' => 0, 'points' => 0);

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    handleMatch($row['home'], $row['scoreHome'], $row['scoreAway']);
    handleMatch($row['away'], $row['scoreAway'], $row['scoreHome']);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( usort($standings, 'comparePoints' ) );  
}

function handleMatch($team, $scoreHome, $scoreAway){
    global $standings, $standingTemplate;
    if ($scoreHome > $scoreAway) 
    {
    $points = 3;
    $win = 1;
    $draw = 0;
    $loss = 0;
}
elseif ($scoreHome == $scoreAway) 
{
    $points = 1;
    $win = 0;
    $draw = 1;
    $loss = 0;
}
else 
{
    $points = 0;
    $win = 0;
    $draw = 0;
    $loss = 1;
}

if ( empty($standings[$team])){
    $standing = $standingTemplate;
} else {
    $standing = $standings[$team];


$standingTemplate['matches']++;
$standingTemplate['wins'] += $win;
$standingTemplate['draws'] += $draw;
$standingTemplate['losses'] += $loss;
$standingTemplate['scoreHome'] += $scoreHome;
$standingTemplate['scoreAway'] += $scoreAway;
$standingTemplate['goalsdiff'] += $scoreHome - $scoreAway;
$standingTemplate['points'] += $points;
}

$standings[$team] = $standing;

 }

function comparePoints($a, $b){
    if ($a['points'] == $b['points']) {
    if ($a['goalsdiff'] == $b['goalsdiff']) return 0;
    return ($a['goalsdiff'] < $b['goalsdiff']) ? 1 : -1 ;
    }       
    return ($a['points'] < $b['points']) ? 1 : -1 ;
    }
```

Comment: The mysql tag is there because it accesses the info from database.

Comment: @janip, but there is no code accessing a database in your post

Comment: yes I didn't copy it. Here I edited it.

Comment: While I'm quite a fan of doing this stuff in the front end, in this instance I think I'd do it in the database. See for instance http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#804

Answer (score 0):

You are printing result of [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which is a boolean value. If you expect an array representation, then print the array itself:

```
usort($standings, 'comparePoints');
print_r($standings);
```

Comment: @janip, at least this is the way to print the array. If it's empty, then probably there is nothing added to the array. Have you read [MCVE]( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: yes I'm figuring out why there's no input to the array.